# How to select and toggle hide on children divs of selected element in Jquery

Tags: html, show-hide, children, jquery

I'm quite new to Jquery and have a problem when I try to select child divs in my program. The point is to have a button that fires a jquery function. This function is meant to get all children divs from where the button is and hide them. Here is my jquery code:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(this).children('div').fadeToggle("fast", function () {
    });
});
```

My html is quite simple. A div within a div and within the second div are two more divs.

```
<div class="clients>
    <input type="button" class="button" id="button" value="Hide Sites" autopostback="false"/>
    <div class="websites>
        <div class="urls"></div>
        <div class="data"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is not working though. I've tried using jquery.next and siblings but couldn't get these to work either. Jquery.closest looked upwards and found the container div (clients) but this wasn't what I needed either. Guys help? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have broken html, `closing quote missing` here `class="clients` and here `class="websites`
 and you have to use **[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** instead of **[children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)**

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Te2Z/1/)**

```
<div class="clients">
    <input type="button" class="button" id="button" value="Hide Sites" autopostback="false"/>
    <div class="websites">
        <div class="urls">1</div>
        <div class="data">2</div>
    </div>
</div>​

$(".button").click(function () {
    $(this).next('div').fadeToggle("fast", function () {
    });
});
```

Comment: the "broken html" are typo's that only apply to this page. I translate my class names for your guys' benefit and forgot the closing quotes. I'm not sure as to why your example works and my code doesn't. I will recheck all my closing tags...

Comment: Have you added jquery library in the page?

Comment: @Adil yes the library is added. I rechecked all my open and close div tags and everything is looking ok.

Comment: Solved it by using .siblings and rearranging my div's. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

try this format

```
$('.clients').on('click', $('.button'), function(){

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help me either. Thanks anyway. I just get the sme result. No JS errors just nothing happens.

Comment: Solved it by using .siblings and rearranging my div's. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using jquery.siblings:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('div').fadeToggle("fast", function () {
    });
});
```

I had previously tried siblings but I guess I had an error because now its working.
Thank you all!